# how to plugin the jquery in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
  var getCanvas; // global variable
  html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {

      getCanvas = canvas;
    }
  });
  var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };
  $("#cmd").on('click', function() {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#cmd").attr("download", "Sample_Pic.png").attr("href", newData);

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML($('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
  });


});
```

```css
.button {
    appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none; font: menu; color: ButtonText;
    display: inline-block; padding: 2px 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="alpha1/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="shot.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shot.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="html-content-holder" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; width: 500px;
        padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <div id="target">
      <div id="content">
        <h3>Hello, this is mathit app</h3>
        <a class="upload">Upload to Formulas</a>
        <h2>
                        This is <b>10th Std Notes</b> <span style="color: red"></span>
                    </h2>
        <p>Study about The polynomial of degree two is called quadratic polynomial and equation corresponding to a quadratic polynomial P(x) is called a quadratic equation in variable x. Thus, P(x) = ax2 + bx + c =0, R is known as the standard form of quadratic
          equation. There are two types of quadratic equation. (i) Complete quadratic equation : The equation ax2 + bx + c =0 where a,b,c is not equal to 0. (ii) Pure quadratic equation : An equation in the form of ax2 = 0, a is not equal to 0, b,c is
          equal to 0.</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a id="cmd" href="#" class="button">generate PDF</a>
  <br/>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I have some code how to plugin the jquery(or)js link the html2canvas method in this code run the script $ symbol not define are indicate my notepad so how to link and how to download the pdf and png image.please help me its very useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,if it works for you :

```
<html>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>
            <p>a pararaph</p>
        </div>
        <div id="editor"></div>
        <button id="cmd">generate PDF and Image</button>

        <br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#cmd').click(function () {
                         pdf();
                            capture();
                        });         
                }); 
                function pdf()
                {
                    var doc = new jsPDF();
                    var specialElementHandlers = {
                        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    };      
                    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
                        'width': 170,
                            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                    });
                    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');            
                }   

                function capture() {
                    html2canvas($('body'),{
                        onrendered: function (canvas) {                     
                               var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                               var a = document.createElement('a');
                               a.href = imgString;
                               a.download = "image.png";
                               document.body.appendChild(a);
                               a.click();
                               document.body.removeChild(a);              
                    }
                });
            }     
               </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: its work but  only download the image i want  how to download the pdf and png image

Comment: please help its  very useful

Comment: I have edited the code..check it..I have checked it and it is working properly.If pdf and image are not getting downloaded on your browser then change the browser setting for allowing multiple downloads.

Comment: Was it helpful for you?